# Is the same Windows registry shared between all user profiles?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu, user-profiles

I have two user profiles on my Windows 10 PC, a developer profile and a regular profile. In the developer profile, I ran a `.reg` file to add a context menu item that opens a Windows Terminal instance with an active Git Bash prompt.

To my surprise, the context menu in the other Windows profile also showed the new menu option, but when clicked, it showed an error that said it cannot access the path or file specified. This is because I don't have Windows Terminal installed in the regular profile. And deleting the registry keys in question in the regular profile also removes the menu item from the context menu in the developer profile.

Is the same Windows registry being shared between the two profiles and causing this to happen? If so, how can I have a separate registry for each user profile?

**Reg File:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\windowsterminal]
@="Open Windows Terminal Here"
"Icon"="%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\WTerminal\\terminal.ico"
        
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\windowsterminal\command]
@="wt new-tab --profile \"Git Bash\" --startingDirectory ."
```

Comment: There is only one registry. It might help if you would include the contents of the `.reg`

Comment: @mashuptwice I edited the question to include the contents of the reg file. Thanks.

Comment: @mashuptwice Is there a way to give each user profile its own copy of the registry? I don't want reg keys added for the developer user profile to affect the regular profile.

Comment: You need to add the value to HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59917614/edit-the-windows-explorer-context-menu-for-only-a-single-user

Comment: @mashuptwice This is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes and no. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is shared; `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is private per-user.

Meanwhile HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a *virtual* tree that's actually [a merged view](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) of both the per-user `HKCU\Software\Classes` and `HKLM\Software\Classes` trees. (It's a leftover from Windows 9x, which didn't have the separation.)

Writes done to HKCR will go to either the personal or system registry depending on your privileges, and depending on whether the key being updated was originally loaded from HKCU or HKLM.

To have per-user file associations, put them in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead of using HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Similarly, to create system-wide ones, put them in HKLM.

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-hives. **HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG** System, System.alt, System.log, System.sav 
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER** Ntuser.dat, Ntuser.dat.log 
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM** [Where security settings are stored] Sam, Sam.log, Sam.sav 
***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security*** Security, Security.log, Security.sav 
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software** Software, Software.log, Software.sav 
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System** System, System.alt, System.log, System.sav 
**HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT** Default, Default.log, Default.sav

Comment: HKCR is from Windows 3 but not actually a leftover, Windows does read from it.

Comment: @Anders "leftover" means that the *design* is a leftover from Windows 3 (as you correctly note) - indeed it's still active.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, there's a single registry The registry has a number of real hives, and a number of "virtual" hives. Two of the most important real hives are `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_USERS`. As the latter implies, it holds values for multiple users.

Now `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a virtual mapping of one `HKEY_USERS` sub-key, roughly speaking the key of the user that started the process. Hence, different processes might have different `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` mappings. Similary, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is also a virtual view, formed by merging `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and that `HKEY_USERS` sub-key.

The registry supports Access Control Lists (ACL's) so you might not be able to see keys from other users, though.

Comment: There's no `HKEY_USERS` hive storing values for multiple users.  `HKEY_USERS` is a container within which per-user hives become mounted (only while that user profile is loaded), all the values belonging to that user are stored separately from other users and separately from the common hives.

Comment: @BenVoigt: And the HKLM part is its own file. The storage backing the registry is a fairly irrelevant detail. Conceptually, it's one entity.

Comment: The storage of `HKEY_USERS` as a bunch of separate per-user hives is not irrelevant, the fact that those portions of the registry appear and disappear with `LoadUserProfile()` is very visible.

Comment: Also, [the meaning of "hive"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-hives) is focused on the separated storage.  Calling `HKEY_USERS` a hive is just plain incorrect.